# Querying historical balance data from a transactions table

Tags: postgresql

In need of help to get the total balances of customers on a daily basis if I backtracked the data.

I have the following table structures in a Postgres database:

```
Table1: accounts (acc)
|id|acc_created|
|1 |2019-01-01 |
|2 |2019-01-01 |
|3 |2019-01-01 |

Table2: transactions
|transaction_id|acc_id|balance|txn_created        |
|1             |1     |100    |2019-01-01 07:00:00|
|2             |1     |50     |2019-01-01 16:32:10|
|3             |1     |25     |2019-01-01 22:10:59|
|4             |2     |200    |2019-01-02 18:34:22|
|5             |3     |150    |2019-01-02 15:09:43|
|6             |1     |125    |2019-01-04 04:52:31|
|7             |1     |0      |2019-01-05 05:10:00|
|8             |2     |300    |2019-01-05 12:34:56|
|9             |3     |120    |2019-01-06 23:59:59|
```

The transactions table shows the balance after a transaction is made on the account.

To be honest, I am unsure how to write the query, or whether I am overthinking the situation. I know it would involve last_value() and coalesce(), and possibly lag() and lead(). Essentially the criterias I would like to fulfill are:

- It takes the last balance value of that day, for that account. 
  (i.e. the balance for acc_id = '1' on 2019-01-01 would be $25, acc_id ='2' and '3' would be $0)
- For days where there are no transaction made by an account, the balance would take from the previous balance of that account.
  (i.e. the balance for acc_id = '1' on 2019-01-03 would be $25)
- Lastly, I would like the total balance of all accounts aggregated by date.
  (i.e. At end of 2019-01-02, the total balance should be $375 (=25+200+150)

I have tried the query below:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day',date), sum(balance_of_day) FROM (
SELECT txn.created as date,
       acc_id,
       row_number() over (partition BY acc_id ORDER BY txn_created ASC) as order_of_created,
       last_value(balance) over (partition by acc_id ORDER BY txn_created RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as balance_of_day
FROM transactions) X
where X.order_of_created = 1
GROUP BY 1
```

However, this only gives me the total balance if a transaction was made by any account on a certain day.

The expected end result (based on the example) should be:

```
|date       |total_balance|
|2019-01-01 |25           |
|2019-01-02 |375          |
|2019-01-03 |375          |
|2019-01-04 |475          |
|2019-01-05 |450          |
|2019-01-06 |420          |
```

I won't need to present the different account numbers, just the total accumulated balance from all customers at the end of the day. Please let me know how I can solve this! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a few cool postgres feature to accomplish this.  First, to get the last balance per day, use DISTINCT ON:

```
SELECT DISTINCT on(acc_id, txn_created::date)
  transaction_id, acc_id, balance, txn_created::date as day
  FROM transactions
  ORDER BY acc_id, txn_created::date, txn_created desc;
```

To figure out the balance on any given day, we'll use a daterange per row that includes the current row and excludes the next row, partitioned by acc_id:

```
SELECT transaction_id, acc_id, balance, daterange(day, lead(day, 1) OVER (partition by acc_id order by day), '[)')
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT on(acc_id, txn_created::date)
  transaction_id, acc_id, balance, txn_created::date as day
  FROM transactions
  ORDER BY acc_id, txn_created::date, txn_created desc
) sub;
```

Lastly, join to generate_series.  We can join where the date in generate_series is contained by the daterange we created in the last step.  The dateranges are intentionally not overlapping, so we can query on any date safely.

```
WITH balances as (
  SELECT transaction_id, acc_id, balance, daterange(day, lead(day, 1) OVER (partition by acc_id order by day), '[)') as drange
  FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT on(acc_id, txn_created::date)
  transaction_id, acc_id, balance, txn_created::date as day
  FROM transactions
  ORDER BY acc_id, txn_created::date, txn_created desc
  ) sub
)
SELECT d::date, sum(balance)
FROM generate_series('2019-01-01'::date, '2019-01-06'::date, '1 day') as g(d)
JOIN balances ON d::date <@ drange
GROUP BY d::date;

     d      | sum
------------+-----
 2019-01-01 |  25
 2019-01-02 | 375
 2019-01-03 | 375
 2019-01-04 | 475
 2019-01-05 | 450
 2019-01-06 | 420
(6 rows)
```

[Here's a fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e3b9145ca34d0d0d1e0ccffaa9afa729)

Comment: Many thanks for the help! I just tested it and it worked wonderfully! will have a read on the syntax for `<@` and `multiple variable DISTINCTs` to see how they work :)

Comment: Note that this uses `DISTINCT ON` which is different from  `DISTINCT`.  It's a very useful postgres feature to get the top value by a specific criteria.